# Accidentally removed my /mnt folder

Tags: directory, delete

sorry for this stupid question, but I accidentally deleted my /mnt folder. Are there ways to recover that? (rm -rf /mnt/)

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Sorry, I missed it:

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Release:    18.04

Codename:   bionic

Comment: Recreate the dir as root with `sudo mkdir /mnt` and then re-mount any mount points that may have been there.

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/mnt` is an empty directory by default.

You can re-create it by running

```
sudo mkdir /mnt
```

But if you had something mounted there, that is not that easy. You probably removed everything from the mounted device.

Comment: Thx, the re-creation was not that problem, I was more wondering if I have to reset something. But so far I cannot see anything missing. Thanks for your further explanation.

Maybe lucky me this time. :-)

Comment: If you didn't use `/mnt` for any specific purpose, removing it doesn't affect anything at all.

Comment: Upvoted because it all made sense until "But". The question is about how to create `/mnt` and we can only speculate about demise.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are in the root directory by typing `cd /`. You should be able to type `sudo mkdir mnt` to (re)create the mnt folder.

Comment: codlord's method will work, I did not refresh my browser so I did not see that someone had already posted a response.